# How to set margin between section number and section title in TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, titlesec, titletoc

I want to create a TOC, that will have equal margins between section numbers and section titles regardless of the number of digits in section number.

I have an example of solution, but I want to use `titlesec` to define my sections.

```
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]
{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \vskip 1.5ex%  
    {\bf\thesubsection \ #1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection{\hspace{1em}\thesubsection\hspace{0.5em}#1}%
  \vskip 1.5ex %  
}%
```

Here is my try with `titletoc` It's seems to be right, but I can have a huge amount of sections and subsections in my document, so the reserved space will end up soon.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[3.5em]{}{3.2em}{1pc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection1}

\subsection{Subsection2}

\subsection{Subsection3}

\subsection{Subsection4}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC with titlesec]

MWE with redefined subsection:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]
{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \vskip 1.5ex%  
    {\bf\thesubsection \ #1}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\hspace{1em}\thesubsection\hspace{0.5em}#1}%
  \vskip 1.5ex %  
}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection1}

\subsection{Subsection2}

\subsection{Subsection3}

\subsection{Subsection4}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC with redefined subsection]

Comment: Why don't you use also `titlesec` for your subsections? On the other hand, I don't understand very well the problem with using `titletoc`?

Comment: @Bernard | use `titlesec` for my subsections, but I suppressed my subsections definitions to show only TOC.

Comment: @Bernard The problem with `titletoc` is  that I can't understand how to set equal margins between section number and section title with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand quite well. Do you mean the, for instance, the gap between `10` and `Section` is  not the same as between `9` and its title?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, it is

Answer (score 1):

I can propose this, with the `rightlabels` option and some trial and errors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[rightlabels]{titletoc}%
\dottedcontents{section}[1.7em]{}{1.5em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[4.25em]{\small}{4.25em}{1pc}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection1}

\subsection{Subsection2}

\subsection{Subsection3}

\subsection{Subsection4}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\subsection{SubsectionN}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tocloft` package.

My apologies, I initially used the `memoir` code but the following works for the `article` class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{...} % resets space for section number (usually 2.3em)
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{...} % resets space for subsection number (usually 3.2em)
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
% ...
\end{document}
```

Change the `...numwidths` to suit your numbering scheme.

Comment: Do `titlesec` and `tocloft` play well together?

Comment: This doesn't work with `article`, only with `memoir`

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't know. Any ideas?

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't know. It may depend on what the user is trying to do. Any ideas. (I tried to edit my earlier comment but SE has a 5 minute space in which you can do so! (I started within the limit but ended outside it. Not a good user interface!)

Comment: @ShalomAlecheim Thnk you. I have modified my answer.